# Allow push notifications in XCODE without using a mac for development

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic 2 app. I am developing it on windows machine, but I have access to a mac, where I generated the development certificate.

I am following [this walk-through](http://docs.ionic.io/services/profiles/) and I am  at the Enable Push section. I just downloaded the .mobileprovision file. Problems are:

- double clicking on the .mobileprovision file results in "apple configurator 2 cannot open files in the .provisioning profile format"
- should I develop my app(have my source code)  on the mac itself to be able to open it in XCODE. I though I might be able to open it based on AppID I created on developer.apple.com. On the MAC I only have the certificates and the .mobileprovision file

Comment: For generating certificates you need a Mac system without Mac u r not able to generate certificates.

Comment: Yes, and I have a Mac, but my development process is not on it. Question is how can I open it in xcode to edit project settings, since all my development is based on my windows machine(and is not swift/objective c)?

Comment: How do you compile your app and deploy on iphone? don't you need xcode to do that? Even though you do development in Ionic, adding iOS platform will generate XCode project only. So for deploying on ios device, you need a mac. And while compiling, use the proper profile for push notification.

Comment: It seems that I missed something. Shouldn't I have the certificates in order to deploy my app? In other words, don't certificates come before deployment? Otherwise, so far I've used IonicView, because it is in an early stage.

Comment: Yes. While development you might use chrome for testing. but for deploying on ios device, you need a mac(to compile), team id (comes with an apple developer account) for certificate and profile with the developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I have my development on a Windows machine. I was following tutorials for Mac, because I have a Mac. But in the tutorials, the dev environment is on the Mac itself. So I was looking for a solution that will not require for me to create another dev environment(ide, installing packages, etc).

In the end, it turned out that I needed to set up a dev environment on the Mac itself as well. This is the only way to open your project in XCode where all the work(certificates, profiles) is done.

I needed to install **Ionic**, **Node**, **Visual Studio Code** and get the repository from **Bitbucket** and then build my project in order to get the **xproject** file. Now I can proceed with the tutorials over publishing to the App Store and push notifications.